# Filtering a collection is not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I  have a collection named "colLast500" which contain 2 main SharePoint fields; "PRF Status" which is of type single-line + "Channel" which is of type choice which allow multiple section. and i am filtering it using a Combo Box named "hdrStatus_main". and i want to define these filtering rules:-

```
 Filter(
        colLast500,
        'PRF Status' = hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result || IsBlank(hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result),
        (('PRF Status' = "In Promo Setup" && hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result = "Retail Promo Setup" && ("LF" in Concat(Channel,Value & ",") || "SF" in Concat(Channel,Value & ","))) || (hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result <> "Retail Promo Setup")),
       (('PRF Status' = "In Promo Setup" && hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result = "Online Promo Setup" && ("Online" in Concat(Channel,Value & ",") )) || (hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result <> "Online Promo Setup")))
```

but currently if i select `hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result = "Retail Promo Setup"` and the item Channel contain LF or SF + 'PRF Status' = "In Promo Setup" >> i will not get any result..

Similar case if i select `hdrStatus_main.Selected.Result = "Online Promo Setup"` and there is an item with Channel contain "Online" + 'PRF Status' = "In Promo Setup" >> i will not get any result.

so what could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe delegation issue, how many total items in the list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am not getting any delegation warning , and the list contain only 500 items